# AdminDirectory to get company directory to embed on Google Site

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I've found the below code ([here](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/home/announcements/listingdomainusernamesinaspreadsheet)) to list directory info in a spreadsheet so that I can publish it to our Google Intranet site. I've tested and it works great, but I have the following two issues:

1. The organization property the way it is written displays all info in one column like this: `{customType=Work, location=Sunset Wipes, title=IT Manager, department=IT, primary=true}`. I'm looking to be able to just pull the Title, Department and Location as separate columns. I've tried `organization.title`, `organization[title]`, `organization[title.value]`, but am not sure the correct syntax to just pull individual property values under organization.
2. The phones property the way it is written displays only one phone number and in the format like: `{type=work, value=6118}`. I want to be able to display work, mobile and other phones numbers in separate columns. In the same manner as organizations, I've tried different ways of trying to get this and can't figure out the syntax.

   function writeToSpreadsheet(){
       var values = [];
       var users = AdminDirectory.Users.list({domain:'domain.com'}).users; 
       for (var i=0; i